Girl hangs herself from a building
I don't remember anything else about this movie other than a vivid memory of the following scene:
A girl is standing on top of a building (most probably a university or some such), and she's dressed in a uniform.
Camera follows a boy coming from outside the building when he notices the girl.
Focus back on girl, she has a noose around her neck, she's smiling as well.
The girl then jumps from the building after saying the following "This is all for you, [boy's name]".
Camera goes back to boy's POV and we see the girl hanging from the building.
Can you tell me which movie is this?
Or in case if I am wrong, which TV Series?

You might mean the nanny's suicide in The Omen. She hangs herself from a building after shouting, "[Damien], it's all for you". The remake from 2006 faithfully reenacts the scene with the same dialogue (pic here) so you might mean that. Here is the scene from the original movie [Warning: disturbing]:



